# How to get image extension from wp image editor object?

Tags: images

`get_extension` seems to be a protected method dunno why, seems to me there is no way to get file extension using image editor object...
I know I can use `getimagesize` with php and be done with it but that would mean fetching the image a second time which would be nice to avoid

Comment: Just use `pathinfo`

Comment: $filename in pathinfo requires the path ending with the extension so I would need the extension to get the extension..The thing is that I save the file using the `save()` method of wp image editor object which adds the file extension when saving the file so I cannot even use pathinfo of the saved object, I guess I will use php directly to save the images...anyway the image editor object in wp seems really silly in this way.

Comment: Could you use `pathinfo` on the result from the `generate_filename` method? I'm just guessing by reading the source at https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1.1/src/wp-includes/class-wp-image-editor.php

Comment: `generate_filename` adds the extension itself so there is no need for `pathinfo`, basically every method in the image editor obj retrieves the extension, but it just can't be accessed from the outside...the only problem is the fact that it adds a suffix and it needs to be removed as I specified in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using `generate_filename` yesterday but probably it was kind of late and I was trying and didnt manage to make it work, today I managed to workaround the problem without fetching the image another time like this:

```
$save_path = WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/tmp/' . $img_name . "-" . $nw . "x" . $nh;
$wp_img->save($save_path);
$img_name = basename($wp_img->generate_filename('suffix'));
$img_name = str_replace('-suffix', '', $img_name);
$img_url = content_url() . '/tmp/' . $img_name;
$filepath = WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/tmp/' . $img_name;
```

As you can see a suffix must be specified because currently the method adds a default suffix as the image size by default, and to retrieve the correct image filename + extension it must be removed afterwards.